# Firebase onDataChange() not working on some devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed an app which receiving real time data change from Firebase node.

I am calling below example code for fetching data change if happens in Firebase table for particular node.

```
private class MyValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.i("********** change", dataSnapshot.getKey() + ": " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // If we're not expecting an error, report it to your Firebase console
        FirebaseCrash.report(databaseError.toException());
    }
}
```

**Issue:** 
For example 400 devices are there which are in for my app then out of these 400, randomly 20-30 devices are there which are not getting callback in **onDataChange** method.

I am searching for this from so many days but not able to find the solution.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in the Firebase database servers or SDK that would make this happen randomly. So unless you can get some more details on/from the devices where this happens, it is unlikely that we can help based on just the code you shared. If you have a device where the problem occurs, [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and study the logcat output for hints on whether they can't connect.

Comment: Actually my app is live. The problem occurs for real users. So i am stuck to this